# How to use reverse relation in my query?(django)

Tags: django, django-models, django-queryset

I'm trying to make a query to show all the branches which have the food. I've tried a lot but I can't make it work.
Could someone help me?

Here are my models:

```
class Branch(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    created = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
    is_main = models.BooleanField()
    description = models.TextField(max_length=500)

    food_restaurant_category = models.OneToOneField(FoodRestaurantCategory, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    restaurant = models.ForeignKey(Restaurant, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    branch_address = models.OneToOneField(BranchAddress, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    manager = models.OneToOneField("accounts.Staff", on_delete=models.CASCADE)


class Food(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    image = models.ImageField(upload_to=upload_path)
    description = models.TextField(max_length=500)
    created = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)

    meal_category = models.ManyToManyField(MealCategory, related_name="meal")
    food_restaurant_category = models.ManyToManyField(FoodRestaurantCategory, related_name="food_cat")

class Menu(models.Model):
    inventory = models.PositiveIntegerField()
    price = models.DecimalField(validators=[MinValueValidator(0.0)], max_digits=10, decimal_places=1)

    food = models.ForeignKey(Food, on_delete=models.CASCADE, related_name="food_rel")
    branch = models.ForeignKey(Branch, on_delete=models.CASCADE, related_name="branch_rel")
```

Comment: Share what you have tried so far to solve your problem?

Comment: So what is the input? A `Food` object? And you want all `Branch`es that have a `Menu` that links to that `Food`?

Comment: Is it possible to be more *responsive*.

Comment: @WillemVanOnsem I have 3 tables: Menu, branch and food. I want to make a query to show all the branches which have an specific food. I have tried Branch.objects.filter(...) but I don't know what to write inside the filter. By the way I want to write the query inside my views.py

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can obtain the `Branch`es for which there is a `Menu` that links to a `Food` object *`food`* with:

```
Branch.objects.filter(branch_rel__food=food)
```

It however does not seem to make much sense to specify `related_name='food_rel'` and `related_name='branch_rel'` since this is the name of the relation in reverse, likely `related_name='menus'`, in that case you filter with `Branch.objects.filter(menus__food=food)`.